# trying to print 2 arrays in 2 columns on pdf but the first array prints correct while the second array prints clustered, values on top of each other

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

```
$sql = " SELECT Salary,Bonus,Housing_Allowance,Transport_Allowance,Travel_Allowance,Vehicle_Allowance,Cellphone_Allowance,Entertainment_Allowance,Company_Car,Medical_Allowance FROM $tb2_name WHERE Month='$month' AND Year='$year' AND Employee_Number='$user'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

// This code works fine as the array are printed under each other .  thanks to the \n

$data = array();
foreach($rows as $key => $value) {
  if($value > 0) {
    $me =  $key . " : " . $value . "\n";
    $pdf->MultiCell(63, 10, $me, 2);
  }
}
```

The above code works perfect as the array values are printed under each other on the pdf page and not clustered. the problem comes by the next bit of code when i try to do the same thing in the column next to it

```
$pdf->SetXY($x + 35, $y);

$col2="Deductions  Other Deductions   ";


$col3="Deductions\n \n  $DSocial_Security  \n $DContributions \n $DVehicle_Allowance \n $Other_Deductions";

$wql = " SELECT Housing_Allowance,Vehicle_Allowance,Company_Car,DContributions,Pension, Provident_Fund,Retirement_Annuity,Study_Policy FROM $tb2_name WHERE Month='$month' AND Year='$year' AND Employee_Number='$user'";

$results = mysqli_query($conn, $wql);
$rows1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
```

the problem comes here . when this is executed the result is printed on top of each other and clustered and not under each other as the \n says .

```
$data1 = array();
foreach($rows1 as $key => $value) {
  if($value > 0) {
    $me =  $key . " : " . $value . "\n";
     $pdf->SetXY($x + 60 ,$y);
    $pdf->MultiCell(63, 10, $me, 3);
    }


  }

the above code does not print the array so that the values line up under each other but the values line up on top of each other and are clustered.


$pdf->SetXY($x + 95 ,$y);

$pdf->SetXY($x + 120 ,$y);
$pdf->MultiCell(63, 10, $col2, 3);
```

Comment: which extension you used for pdf ?

Answer (score 0):

According to me as per you code/statements Please increase you $x positioning as shown below:

```
$data1 = array();
foreach($rows1 as $key => $value) {
  if($value > 0) {
    $me =  $key . " : " . $value . "\n";
     $pdf->SetXY($x ,$y);
     $pdf->MultiCell(63, 10, $me, 3);
     $x= $x + 5;  // insert this line 
    }
  }
```

At first code MultiCell will increase x by default so its works perfectly. In the second code you specified SetXY() for positioning, so every time you have to increase you X position with required margins.... Thanx